# Jboss Server PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jboss7.x

I am fairly new to using JBoss Server for application deployment, and I am using Jboss eop 7.4 version. I have a java application that is built and deployed as a war file on this jboss server. I am trying to call a 3rd party service from my Java application using REST API but the API used certificate-based authentication. I am able to add the key and cer files given to me by the 3rd party application in postman client and hit the api. However, I am not able to do so from my Java code .

Here's what I tried   -

1. importing the cert file in the java keystore

`keytool -import -alias mycert -keystore "<JAVA_HOME>\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file C:\certs\mycer.cer`

2. importing the cert in the JBoss keystore using similar command as above . I found the Jboss application.keystore file from the standalone.xml file -

```
<security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
```

After each of these steps, I restarted the JVM and the Jboss server respectively.
However I keep getting the following exception -

```
18:06:17,878 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
18:06:17,878 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
18:06:17,882 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
```

here's my Java code -

```
URL url = new URL(<configured url>);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            LOGGER.info(System.getProperty("java.home"));
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String response = new String();
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; response += line);
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n"+response);
          
            conn.disconnect();
```